# VM virtual audio card not making sound

Tags: rhel, audio, virtual-machine, libvirt

I am running a rhel 6 vm on a rhel 7 host; the rhel 7 host has a sound card and I am able to use the speaker-test command to hear sounds. Then I added virtual sound card (AC97, using virt-manager) to the rhel 6 vm but cannot figure out why I can't get sound from the vm.

Very unfamiliar with the sound linux programs here are some of the things I have tried based on internet searching (forgot to track all the changes made...):

1) added QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=pa in /etc/sysconfig/libvirtd

2) changed vnc_allow_host_audio = 0 to vnc_allow_host_audio = 1 in /et/libvirt/qemu.conf; and added user and group fields

After rebooting both systems many times, I am very very confused; has anyone else experienced this issue??

Comment: Have you checked the audio mixer settings on the VM? The virtual sound card might have its output volume set to zero.

Comment: First pick the method you want. You can either "steal" your real audio card from host and give it to the VM, or you can use an emulated audio card in the VM, and play the sound on the host e.g. via Pulseaudio (`QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=pa`), assuming Pulseaudio is running (did you check?). You can't do both at the same time. Which do you want? Then go through your configuration files and make the changes for the correct alternative.

Comment: So I want to use the virtual sound card. And Pulseaudio that should be running on the host or the guest (or both??); currently Pulseaudio daemon runs on the host. Also yes, I have checked the sound card volumes are not set to zero. I read some where that there is a configuration for pulseaudio to allow multiple audio sources (virtual and hardware); but can't figure it out for rhel